# Why is my "c" variable growing exponentially when it reaches the 3rd cycle in the for loop?

Tags: c, string, function, for-loop

I am having a problem, here with a program that is meant to be a data entry routine, the problem in question, is the variable c that goes to the capac function to ask the user for the maximum capacity of the string, when it reaches the 3rd cycle of the for it starts to grow god knows how, making my for, something unusable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


int func_carac(int *car) //function that catches characters introduced by the user
{
  int caracter;

  printf("\nType the character you want: \n");
  caracter = getche();

  *car = caracter;
  return *car;
}

//________________________________________________________\\

int func_capac(int *cap) //function to ask the user for the amount of characters
{
  int quant;

  printf("\nDetermine the maximum character capacity you want to write: ");
  scanf("%d",&quant);

  *cap = quant;

  return *cap;
}

int main()
{
  int car, pos, c, total;
  char vetor[] = {'\0'};

  func_capac(&c);

  total = c + 1;
  vetor[total];
  vetor[total] = '\0';
  printf("%i", c);

  for(pos = 0; pos < c; pos++)
   {
    func_carac(&car);
    if((car >= 97) && (car <= 122) || (car == 32))
     {
      printf("\n%c - Tabela ASCII, %d \n",car ,car);
      printf("%i", c);
    
      vetor[pos] = (char) car;
     }
    else if(car == 8)
     {
      printf("Successfully removed the previous character.");
      pos = pos-2;
     }
    else
     {
      pos--;
     }
   }
  printf("Frase: %s\n",vetor);
}
```

If someone could help me, I would be grateful

Comment: In your functions, why do you use both pass-by-reference emulation *and* return the values? Do one or the other, not both (and I recommend only return value).

Comment: Also you tag this windows, I think, conio.h/getche is not posix.

Comment: As for your problem, C doesn't have dynamic arrays. The array `vector` is defined as containing only a single element. Any non-zero index will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `vetor[total];` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AllanWind Besides going out of bounds of the array.

Comment: ok i'll try to work it out

Comment: omg it worked very well, I have been tearing my hair out of my little head and thanks to you guys I will get some rest

Comment: sorry i'm new in the stack overflow community, i didn't knew i had to accept the answer XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Someprogrammerdude nailed it.  `vector[] = { '\0' }` means that vector is an array of length 1.  As you write to vector after position 0 you end up with undefined behavior (i.e. overwriting c somehow).  Here is the minimal fix:

```
int main()
{
    int car, pos, c, total;

    func_capac(&c);
    total = c + 1;

    char vetor[total];
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) vetor[i] = 0; // or memset(vector, 0, total);
    ...
```